# Maintain the FIFO order of execution of task in thread executor pool

Tags: java, threadpool, fifo

My application is executing the task alloted to it by the other application.For every ten tasks execution application put the progress information in the database. I am using thread executor pool to put the updated information in the database. The problem is that request are not executed in FIFO order in thread pool. For ex: 
FirstRequest :- 10 tasks are executed, so request to store value = 10 is sent to thread pool.
SecondRequest:- Another 10 tasks are executed, request to store value = 20 is sent to thread pool.
The problem arises when second request is executed before first request.
Is there anything i can do with thread pool to maintain the FIFO order ?

Comment: Tasks execute in parallel and there is no guarantee on the order of start or finish of execution of individual tasks. If you want strict order of execution, then execute tasks serially (one after another).

Comment: That's what i was afraid of. The time taken to put the value in database is lot as compared to execution of tasks. So if i make it sequential, the speed of the application will fall drastically. Nevertheless, i guess i will have to make it sequential.

Comment: Why don't you put database operations in a separate thread? That way you can continue processing tasks, while the database is updated with the new values.

Comment: you are kind of saying thread pool with only one thread and large queue.

Comment: I believe that a single thread with a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) should be enough. Main thread will run a loop, execute tasks and put updates into the queue. Another thread will wait on the queue, take updates and execute them, also in a loop.

Comment: Yeah i guess that is the best i can do. Thank You